# How to migrate particular table in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In model file already some of table migration and added records to that tables. Now, I tried to add a additional tables but its not migrating.

```
class Ranking(object):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name= models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.ForeignKey(DecisionModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How can i makemigration & migrate particular table?

Thanks for the solution in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
class Ranking(object):
   # ...
```

You need to inherit from `django.db.models.Model`, not from `object`:

```
from django.db import models

class Ranking(models.Model):
   # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
```

and the simply migrate it

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This would create all tables. Question states "particular table".